# Excel: IF and AND statement for dates, blanks and values

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I've got a spreadsheet which lists the hire start date for our fleet of vehicles, it lists the milage and each car needs a service every 12,000 miles.

I'm trying to use Conditional Formatting to highlight cars which need a service.

First one (less than 12000 miles works fine)

Next one should say this:

If N1 (cell of 2nd service) is blank and mileage (I1) is between 12,000 and 24,000 miles, highlight yellow.

Here it is:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(N1),(I1>24000,I1<12000))
```

As it's in the Conditional Formatting tool it is just giving me a generic error.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: remove some of the `()`: `=IF(AND(ISBLANK(N1),I1>24000,I1<12000))`

Comment: Becareful with the `ISBLANK`  it only sees truly blank cells as blank.  If there is a formula in the cell that returns `""` it will see that as not blank.

Comment: For conditional formatting take the "if(" out, its implied and not necessary. And your references should be semi-absolute like $n1 or $I1 so that it always tests the correct column(s).

Comment: Thanks all.

I have changed it to:

=AND(ISBLANK($N1),$I1>24000,$I1<12000))

but I'm still getting the same generic error.

The cells are truly blank - but good thought Scott.

Best

Comment: based on your comment, your formula should be `=AND(ISBLANK($N1),$I1<24000,$I1>12000)`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for catching

Comment: Ah yes, that's it @GowthamShiva, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Posting the formula as answer as it worked for you,

```
=AND(ISBLANK($N1),$I1<24000,$I1>12000)
```